# Column math on wide data produced by dcast

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I am trying to summarise some data. I have used ddply to create a sum column that produced:

```
   family status sum
1     EMS  Off    77
2     EMS  On    568
3     MWO  Off  1704
4     MWO  On   2600
```

and from this used dcast to convert to wide format as:

```
  family    Off    On 
1    EMS     77   568
2    MWO   1704  2600
```

What I can't figure out is how to add a column to this that is the percentage of 'On' (On/On+Off).

To produce:

```
  family    Off    On Pct
1    EMS     77   568 0.8806
2    MWO   1704  2600 0.6041
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `df$Pct <- with(df, On/(On+Off))` or `df$On/rowSums(df[-1])` or do what hrbrmstr said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat$Pct <- dat$On/(dat$On+dat$Off)

dat

##   family  Off   On       Pct
## 1    EMS   77  568 0.8806202
## 2    MWO 1704 2600 0.6040892
```